# How to Create MySQL Compact Database?

Tags: c#, mysql, local-database, compact-database

I want to use MySQL like [SQL Compact Edition](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17876)!
In other words, I want to create a local database (`compact database file`) by **MySQL** csharp drivers in from [Connector/Net](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.9.html) .

In my project we need first to install [MySql.Data.dll](http://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data/) in the GAC and my `Data Source` is a file path like: `D:\MyDatabase\database.myd`

Now my codes must be like this:

```
 using System;
 using System.Data;
 using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

 public class Test
 {
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       string strConnection = "CREATE DATABASE TestDatabase;";

       MySqlConnection conDatabase = new MySqlConnection("Data Source=D:\MyDatabase\database.myd;Persist Security Info=yes");

       MySqlCommand cmdDatabase = new MySqlCommand(strConnection, conDatabase);

       conDatabase.Open();
       cmdDatabase.ExecuteNonQuery();
       conDatabase.Close();
    }
 }
```

Can I do it ?

Comment: Why you don't use Sqlite?

Comment: I offer to use **Firebird** instead

Comment: Ok, I decide to use Sqlite! Thanks every one for answering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did research on the internet and realized that **MySQL** can not be **compact** and I use **Sqlite** instead of **MySQL**.

Some compact databases:

- Firebird
- SQL Server CE
- Sqlite